# Badly formed question? $\|x\|=1=\|y\|$ and $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$, there is a line segment in the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Show that if a normed linear space $X$ contains linearly independent vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $\|y\|=1$ with $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$, then there is a line segment contained in the unit sphere of $X$.

---

Now since the unit sphere in $X$ is defined as $X=\{a\in X: \|a\|=1\}$, and this means that $x,y$ both lie on the unit sphere of $X$. But $\|x+y\|=2$ and hence they must lie on opposite ends of the sphere, and hence form a straight line through the origin. But then these two vectors aren't linearly independent?

Is this question badly formed or what am I missing?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are at opposite ends of a diameter of the sphere, they you'd have $\|x-y\|=2$ and $x+y=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy True, but what I meant was that the only distance two between two points on a sphere of radius 1, is at opposite ends of the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking too Euclidean! It is entirely possible in an arbitrary normed linear space to have points other than antipodal points that satisfy this property. As an example, consider the points $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ in the unit sphere under the $1$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Good question though!

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even think about that for some reason. Thanks. I now see that this is a good exercise for making me fix this exact lack of thought!

Comment: No, I wouldn't call it a lack of thought. A lack of thought would be to simply accept the counter-intuitive premises of the question without at least attempting to see its wider context. Like I said, good question!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

You have $\|\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y\| = 1$. Let's show for instance that
$\|\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y\| = 1$. Note that 
$$\left\|\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y\right\| \le \frac{1}{3}\|x\| + \frac{2}{3}\|y\|=1$$

If we had $\|\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y\| <1$ then 
$$\left\|\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y\,\right\| = \left\|\frac{1}{4} x + \frac{3}{4}\left( \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y\right)\, \right\| \le \frac{1}{4}\left\|x\right\| + \frac{3}{4}\cdot \left\|\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3}y\,\right\| < 1$$ 
contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the edit! Try to show that the whole segment $[x,y]$ is on the sphere, that is, for every $0 \le \lambda \le 1$ you have $\ | \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \| = 1$.